# Как отключить связи виджетов в Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Сегодня начал юзать **Android Studio**, вставил **кнопку0**, затем **кнопку1**, потом когда передвинул **кнопку0** за ней передвинулась и **кнопка1**. Как данная функция в Android Studio выключается? Уж больно раздражает. 
Спасибо!

Comment: В первую очередь вам надо отказаться от пользования визуальным редактором разметки. После этого посмотреть в `xml` файле что у вас происходит. После этого, если не понятно, то приложить его в текст вопроса и уточнить что именно вам непонятно.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб само собой, но хотелось бы сперва хоть немного породниться с IDE:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Эту функцию никак нельзя отключить в Android Studio, так как такое поведение не имеет ничего общего с вызывающей ваше раздражение IDE.

Это свойство контейнера `RelativeLayout` в котором вы разместили свои кнопки, он позволяет связать виджеты на разметке друг с другом так, что к примеру, кнопка1 всегда будет слева от кнопка2.
 Вам следует узнать побольше о компоновочных контейнерах в разметке и компоновке виджетов с их помощью.

Еще вам следует как можно реже (в идеале никогда) пользоваться визуальным редактором разметки для компоновки интерфейса. Так вы будете раздражаться намного меньше, чем сейчас.

Для того, чтобы писать программы - этому надо учиться. Нельзя просто так взять, накидать кнопок на разметку и думать, что они не будут таскаться друг за другом, а виноват в этом кто то, кроме вас.

Comment: крутой чувак, но думаю, последний абзац может довести новичков до истерики. Пусть пробуют. Хотя, паренек, может, уже забыл что такое SO))

Comment: резко. но спасибо

Comment: @user200192 Ну вообще то это была шутка, может юмор у меня такой своеобразный ..